# Regex for remove special characters in word

Tags: regex, split, ansible

I have a value: "VARIABLE=value0", and I would like to take only the part after equal sign, expectations: "value0".

```
- name: Settig variable
  set_fact:
    db_name: "{{device_name.stdout_lines}}"

- name:
  set_fact:
    db_name: "{{ db_name | regex_replace('^(.*[\\=/])') }}"

- debug:
    var: db_name
```

When the last task is, it prints me: "value0']" (with those two additional signs on the end). Is my regex right? Or how to add new regex to remove those two additional signs "']"?

Comment: You could do the test by yourself to check whether your regex is right or not. If the output value is different to what you expect, then your regex is not correct

Comment: Try `^.*[\\=/]|']$`

Comment: It gives an error: "An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was:   line 1
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.", "stdout": ""}"

Comment: You should escape `'` in the pattern, or the string literal will get "corrupt".

Comment: What is ``[\\=/]`` supposed to match? Did you try to escape `=`? Or match three chars: ``\\``, `=` and `/`?

Comment: Just escape '='

Comment: So, ``\\=`` must be `=`. Try `"{{ db_name | regex_findall(r'^.*[=/](\w+)', r'\1') }}"`. Probably, `regex_search(r'^.*[=/](\w+)', r'\1')` will also work.

Comment: The offending line appears to be:

        db_name: "{{ interface_name.stdout_lines | regex_findall(r'^.*[=/](\w+)', r'\1') }}"
                                                                           ^ here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex works fine. Optionally you may simplify it, or use the split filter.

```
> cat test.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    device_name: "VARIABLE=value0"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "regex_replace 1: {{ device_name | regex_replace('^(.*[\\=/])') }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "regex_replace 2: {{ device_name | regex_replace('.*=') }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "split: {{ device_name.split('=')[1] }}"


> ansible-playbook test.yml | grep msg
    "msg": "regex_replace 1: value0"
    "msg": "regex_replace 2: value0"
    "msg": "split: value0"
```